# Can not integrate YouTrack with TeamCity issue log

Tags: teamcity, devops, youtrack

I have a TeamCity server on the AWS and a free version of the YouTrack on the JetBrains cloud. I try to integrate the TeamCity issue log with YouTrack. I create a user with Admin rights and create a perm token for him.

But when I try to integrate into the Team City I receive an Error:
`Error: Error on line 1: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.`

> Screenshoot here:
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nVEOYeVnvBVUYiZ1xD85YPtRsw2BYYc2/view?usp=sharing

What I do wrong?

Comment: Most likely the server URL is incorrect. Could you share it as well?

Comment: @Jk1 Please see the next link
Youtrack URL:https://afj-solution.myjetbrains.com/
TeamCity URL: http://63.35.15.157:8111/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For YouTrack InCloud the correct server URL includes `/youtrack` suffix, exactly as it's shown in browser address bar.

So instead of `https://afj-solution.myjetbrains.com` it should be `https://afj-solution.myjetbrains.com/youtrack`.